# Header referer with request parameters

Tags: java, jsp, web, jstl

After authorization through Social Networks I want to redirect to previous page, and I use `${header.referer}` for that, but when previous page's URL is something like `http://blabla.com/page?id=5`, `${header.referer}` loses `id=5` and redirects to `http://blabla.com/page?`. 
How to get previous page's full URL address with request parameters and values?

Answer (score 1):

With jsp/servlet for getting referer page url you must `request.getHeader("referer")`.This method return string url with parametrs.You do not lose any parameter and etc.

In jstl for getting referer page you can use `${header.referer}`.Also this code result is string url with parameters.Also you do not lose anything from url if you use JSTL.